# How to print ordered login data from file of the form: user, hour, minutes in C

Tags: c, file, structure

I have the following .txt file, representing the login info (user, hour, minutes):

```
andrew,22,    25
anna,    21, 09
gogu, 22, 26
michael, 23, 44
john,12,43
gigi, 05, 30
```

I want to print them in descending order of the last login time

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAX 300

typedef struct{
    char **user, *line;
    int hour, minutes;
}login;
int checkUser(char *user) // since each line is made of a word and two numbers the user is the one that only contains letters
{
    int i = 0, len = strlen(user);
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(!isalpha(user[i]))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
int checkHour(char *word)
{
    int i = 0, len = strlen(word);
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(!isdigit(word[i]))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
char **readUser(FILE* fin, char *s) // this function reads the user from each line
{
    char **username = NULL;
    char noUsers = 0;
    while(fgets(s, MAX, fin))
    {
        s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0';
        char *user = strtok(s, ",");
        while(user)
        {
            if(checkUser(user))
            {
                char *copy = strdup(user);
                if(!copy)
                {
                    printf("Error copying username.\n");
                    return NULL;
                }
                char **auxUser = realloc(username, (noUsers+1) * sizeof(char*));
                if(!auxUser)
                {
                    printf("Error reallocating memory.\n");
                    free(username);
                    return NULL;
                }
                username = auxUser;
                username[noUsers] = copy;
                noUsers++;
            }
            user = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
    }
    char **aux = realloc(username, (noUsers+1) * sizeof(char*));
    if(aux)
    {
        username = aux;
        username[noUsers] = NULL;
    }
    return username;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Invalid format.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    FILE* fin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(!fin)
    {
        printf("Error opening the file.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char buf[MAX];
    int countLines = 0;
    login *array = NULL;
    login **arrUser = NULL;
    while(fgets(buf, MAX, fin))
    {
        buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0';
        array = realloc(array, (countLines+1) * sizeof(*array));
        array[countLines].line = strdup(buf);
        arrUser[countLines]->user = readUser(fin, buf);
        //array[countLines].hour = atoi(*smth*);
        //array[countLines].minutes = atoi(*smth*);
        countLines++;
    }
    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

So my idea was to copy each username into an array of pointers, since there are 3 comma-separated values out of which 2 are numbers, the username in the value that only contains letters. Now I wanted to have some functions to check which value represents the hour and which one represents the minutes. The thing is, there is virtually no difference between them (they both consist of digits), unless the minutes are >= 24. If I could somehow check them separately I could take two variables and use atoi to convert them to int, then use qsort to check the hours and if equal, further check the minutes. When compiling I have 2 warnings that I don't understand:

```
warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
   65 |   username[noUsers] = copy;
      |           ^
warning: array subscript has type ‘char’ [-Wchar-subscripts]
   75 |  username[noUsers] = NULL;
```

At first, inside the structure user was of type char* but if I wanna get the copy of the word I need char**. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would recommend looking into the `scanf` function. It can be tricky to use but is exactly what you want in your situation. You can pass it a format string which describes what it should expect and then will parse each line for you. With that, you will not even need to use `isalpha`/`isdigit`/`atoi`. Your compiler warnings are caused by `noUsers` having type `char`, and not `int` or `size_t` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, I've got no idea how I didn't notice ```noUsers``` was of type char. I should use scanf inside the while in main and give up on the ```readUser``` function completely, right?